# Смена бита в integer

Tags: c++

Есть переменная типа int. Как сменить конкретные биты этого числа?

Comment: Менять можно разные и биты и руководствуясь разной логикой. Что у вас конкретно вы, конечно же, решили утаить...

Answer (score 4):

Ну, например, так:

```
int i = 0;
// устанавливаем 5-ый бит, считая от нуля
i |= (1 << 5);
// сбрасываем 5-ый бит, считая от нуля
i &= ~(1 << 5);
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/u53AC2

---

Кстати, обычно вам не должно хотеться пользоваться низкоуровневыми операциями наподобие установки конкретных битов. Если вы хотите манипулировать частями какой-то структуры, занимающими лишь часть битов числа, к вашим услугам намного более удобные *битовые поля*.

А если вы хотите просто упаковать биты, пользуйтесь [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) или [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).